# Java serialization - java.lang.ClassCastException Error

Tags: java, serialization

I have a **StorageImpl** class which is serializable. This class has an inner class **Record**.

```
public class StorageImpl <ID, T extends IDataStore<ID>> implements IStorage <T, ID>
{

    private class Record implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long key;
        private List<T> dataList;

        private Record()
        {
            key      = new Long(0);
            dataList = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store and retrieve a **Record** which in turn has

```
private Long key;
private List<T> dataList;
```

Once I retrieve a Record, I can get all the books in **bookList** member of the Record.

```
public class StorageImpl <ID, T extends IDataStore<ID>> implements IStorage <T, ID>
{
    private class Record implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long key;
        private List<T> dataList;

        private Record()
        {
            key      = new Long(0);
            dataList = new ArrayList<T>();
        }

    private String dataFile;
    private Record record;

    public StorageImpl(String dataFile)
    {
        this.dataFile = dataFile;
        record        = new Record();
    }


    public List<T> retrieve() throws Exception
    {
        List<T> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

        File file = new File(dataFile);

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            return dataList;
        }        

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
        {
            record = (Record) ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < record.dataList.size(); i++) 
        {
            dataList.add(record.dataList.get(i));
        }

        return dataList;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void store(T t) throws Exception
    {
       List<T> dataList = retrieve();

       ++record.key;        
       t.setID((ID) record.key);
       dataList.add(t);

       record.dataList = dataList;
               writeData(record);
    }
    private void writeData(Record record)
    {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos))
        {
            oos.writeObject(record);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Please note I want to persist just a **Record** and not a **List**.

The error after code changes looks like relates to **Record** not being serializable:

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:

```
atjava.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at StorageImpl.writeData(StorageImpl..java:159)
```

And this is the call inside writeData() at line 159

```
oos.writeObject(record);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're reading the whole list from the file, but casting it to be a single `Record`.

To load an `ArrayList` containing `Record` objects you need `Record` to be serializable, but you're still loading the entire `ArrayList`, so the cast is incorrect (i.e. you can just store the result directly into `recordList`).

```
List<Record> recordList = new  ArrayList<>();

try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
{
    recordList = (List<Record>) ois.readObject();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But I do not want to persist or read a list of records **List<Record>**. I want to persist or read just a **Record** which in turn has a key and a list of all the books in this case. Once I retrieve a **Record**, I can get all the books in **bookList** member of the **Record**. I will update my question.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think the core of the problem is still the same, in that you have stored a list. So if the expected behavior is that you should read a record, then the problem is probably with your store call, because that is, i'm guessing, still storing just the list.

Comment: Thank you. As per your feedback, I have updated my question with more details. If you get a chance to review it again, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That looks like it should run to me. Make sure you've not got a left-over file from the previous version (i.e. one that i storing an array and not a record).

Comment: I am now getting java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException on the read and write call. It looks like Record is not serializable. I am lost.

Comment: I can get the code to run if you extract the Record (i.e. put it in it's own file, not as an inner class). I think there are issues with seriaizability and inner classes.

Comment: Thank you. I will let you know after I try your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I extracted the Record into in its own file and everything works fine now.